# Non-uniform control flow vs Select (in compute shaders)

Tags: gpu, compute-shader

I try to understand better the consequences of non-uniform control flow as defined by [SPIRV spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/SPIR-V/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#UniformControlFlow).

Let `x`, `a` and `b` be non-uniform `f32` values.
Here are two equivalent [wgsl](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/) code fragments.

**Code A:**

```
if x > 0u {
  y = a * x + b;
} else {
  y = x;
}
```

Here the presence of non-uniform `x` in the condition causes a divergent divergent control flow. IIUC this divergent `if` is compiled into [condition codes (a.k.a. predication)](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems2/part-iv-general-purpose-computation-gpus-primer/chapter-34-gpu-flow-control-idioms) and each lane of the GPU SIMD units run through both branches.

If there is a high locality and the condition `x > 0u` happens to have the same result on every lane of the GPU SIMD units, then the unit will jump.

**Code B:**

```
y = select(a * x + b, x, x > 0u);
```

Here there is no divergent workflow, however both computations are made in any cases.

**Question:**

We often read to avoid non-uniform control flow which encourage to write Code B.
However it looks like Code A can sometime skip some computation and is more natural.

What is the rule of thumb here? Which one should we favor?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb for making micro-optimizations like this, it's best to start out with traditional control flow (your "Code A" example) to ensure your program runs correctly, and to provide a baseline for comparison when profiling optimized versions.

In terms of branch-free programming on GPUs specifically, you are making an assumption about the likelihood of divergence.

If your workload is likely to allow many uniform branches, conditional control flow often brings a performance improvement. Imagine a compute workload that's processing a framebuffer, but only a contiguous subset of pixels (e.g. a rectangle on the screen) need to be processed. All the groups that lie entirely outside that region would be able to return early, freeing execution units for scheduling of other tasks or of groups that fall within that work area. Only a small fraction of work groups would end up partially on/off the region and be stuck with some idle threads. A good example of this would be a broadphase test in a raytracing shader, where an entire group of threads may be allowed to skip testing any triangles in an object if none of them intersect the object's bounding box, saving lots of GPU time.

In contrast, if your workload is likely to involve very non-uniform branching, on average you will have many groups being left with idle threads while they wait for the other branch direction to execute. As an extreme example, you could imagine a sort of "switch" statement in a shader that branches a different way for each thread in a work group. In such a situation, it might be worth transforming the various cases into a branch-free calculation which may be more expensive than the original logic, but can be executed on all threads simultaneously rather than forcing them to execute serially.

As always though, don't ever do performance optimization without profiling the results and comparing them to a simpler implementation. Don't sacrifice clean, maintainable code unless you have quantitative evidence that the optimized version is worth the extra complexity.